# Aws - End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I have a django application that does some heavy computation. It works very good with less data on my machine and on 'aws -elasticbeanstalk' as well. But When the data becomes large it on aws, gives, internal server error, and in the logs it shows:

> [core:error]End of script output before headers: wsgi.py

However works fine on my machine

The code where it constantly gives this error is :

```
[my_big_lst[int(i[0][1])-1].appendleft((int(i[0][0]) - i[1]))  for i in itertools.product(zipped_list,temp_list)]
```

where:

- `my_big_lst` is a big list of deques
- `zipped_list` is a large list of tuples
- `temp_list` is a large list of numbers

It is notable, that as data grows large, the processing time also increases, and also that this problem is only coming on aws when data is large, and on my machine, it always works fine.

Update:
I worked out, that this error happens when the processing time exceeds 60 seconds, I also changed the Idle Loadbalancer time to 3600, but no effect, still error is there

Please anyone suggest a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a c-extension module, You could try setting

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

in your virtualhost.

Something about python subinterpreters not working with c-extension modules. However since your code works for a smaller data set, your problem might be solved by setting memory-specific directives.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ApplicationIssues.wiki#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API